# Submit multiple form with one button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, buttonclick

I know this question has been asked a lot, but there doesn't seem to be an answer for me. I'm sorry if I'm just really dumb, but I've been stuck for a day now..

I want to select a table row(see below), and then delete that user. Since I want to have multiple form's to interact with the table I can't place them in one form.

```js
$("#clickMe").click(function () {
    $(".myForms").trigger('submit');
});
 
$('.myForms').submit(function () {
    console.log("SWAGGG");
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="listForm" action="index.php?p=admin" method="POST">
  <?php

$userQuery = "SELECT * FROM usr2";
$row_userQuery = $dbportal->query($userQuery);
if(isset($row_userQuery) && !empty($row_userQuery))
{
    //row[0] = ID
    //row[1] = username(abbrevation)
    //row[2] = admin? 0=normale user 1=admin
    echo'
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
            <tr><td></td><td>User ID</td><td>username</td><td>Role</td></tr>';
    foreach ($row_userQuery as $row)
    {
        echo'
        <tr> 
            <td id="tdSelect"> <input type="checkbox" name="selectedUser[]" value="'. $row[0] .'" />
            <td>'. $row[0] .'</td>
            <td>'. $row[1] .'</td>
            <td>'. $row[2] .'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    echo'</table>';
}

?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="listForm">
</form>

<form id="deleteForm" class="myForms" action="index.php?p=admin" method="POST">
    <div class="leftTextBox">
     <p>user ID:</p>
  <p class="margin">gebruikersnaam:</p>
 </div>
 <div class="rightTextBox">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="userID" placeholder="user ID">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="login" placeholder="gebruikersnaam" style="margin-top: 8px;">
 </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteForm">
 </form>
 <button id="clickMe" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:5px;float:right;">Delete user</button>
```

I'm sure that its just me overseeing something, but help would greatly be appriciated.
Also, I have ajaxForm plugin installed.

Comment: I noticed that your php code has constant for an id: id="tdSelect". I think it would be practical to make the id unique with code sth like: id="tdSelectId'. $row[0] .'"

Comment: @jyrkim Yeah you're right, but I wanted to test something. Thanks for noticing though, I kinda forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'submit' is by definition a jump to a new URL. You know this can only be done for one form at a time.

However, we talking normal 'submits' here, and you don't have to use normal submits to get information from a form and act on it.

Since you're using JQuery, you could use that. Have a look at ajax calls. For instance here:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post

Look for the example called: *Post a form using ajax and put results in a div*, you will find useful code there. It shows you how to get the values of the fields in the form.

Comment: For some reason, it stops at `posting.done(function( data ) {` Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Let's imagine you have 3 forms like this:

```
<form id="form1" action="api/url1">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
</form>
<form id="form2" action="api/url2">
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
</form>
<form id="form3" action="api/url3">
    <input name="field3" type="text" />
</form>

<button>Submit</button>
```

Then you can fire the submit of each form like this:

```
$('button').on("click", function () {
    $('form').each(function (index, form) {
        $(form).submit();
    });
});
```

Then to prevent form full post back just prevent the default of the submit event and then post the serialized form with ajax:

```
$('form').on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error({ status: error.status, statusText: error.statusText })
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u5Lxhxpm/1/)

Comment: My example would return a 404 as the sample action URLs provide do not exist. They are only meant as examples. Replace them with your own API urls

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ajax
you can group a data of all input and post using `new FormData()`

```js
function fnSubmintAll(){
   var formData = new FormData();
    $("#form1,#form2,#form3").each(function(idx,item){
        var frmValue = $(item).serializeArray();
        $.each(frmValue, function (key, input) {
            formData.append(input.name,input.value);
        });
    })


    $.ajax({
        url: "/PostUrl",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType:false,
        processData: false, 
        success: function (result) { 
           alert("Success")
        },
        error: function () {
          alert("Error")
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset> 
<legend>From 1</legend>
<form id="form1">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
</form>
</fieldset>    
<fieldset> 
<legend>From 2</legend>
<form id="form2">
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
</form>
</fieldset>   
<fieldset> 
<legend>From 3</legend>
<form id="form3">
    <input name="field3" type="text" />
</form>
</fieldset>   
<br />
<br />
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="fnSubmintAll">Submit All</button>
```